# phantomjs php script from cron

Tags: php, cron, console, phantomjs

I try to parse a web page with phantomjs and I got into a problem that I can't figure out.
The page gives an error if you try to load it too many times, and there's my problem.

I have a php file `file.php` with `$result = shell_exec('~/tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs  ~/www/phantomscript.js 2>&1');`

If I load that `file.php` in a browser, it works fine, it displays the page content.

But if I try it to run it from cron `php path/to/file.php` it displays the error that I tried too many times...

My question is, what could be the problem that, the same `file.php` works fine in a browser but it doesn-t work if it's loaded in console or cron.

My guess is that it's something to do with the way php works, if a script is loaded into a browser or ran from console. Maybe you can give me a hint or something.

Thanks.

Comment: could it be that `~` is different from cron? Try using full paths.

Comment: Are you sure that the error is generated by a web page? What is the exact wording? How often do you run that cron job? Maybe your sever IP is banned from accessing that page? Try to access it using your server SSH connection as proxy. @pguardiario is right, try with absolute paths to PhantomJS and script.

Comment: The error is "The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator. Your support ID is: long_number". I "fixed" the problem by loading the file trouhg file_get_conent and the web url of the script, not running it trough php in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer, but, an ugly hack.

It seems to work for now, but I still would like to know why it does that.

I made another php file with a single line
`file_get_contents('http://the/web/url/of/the/file.php')`

And i use that file in the cron job.

And, that seems to work, it loads the page.